# Why is this surface integral incorrect?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

$$f= (x+y) $$
$$S = r(u,v) = \langle 4\cos(u),4\sin(u),v\rangle$$
$u$ bounds are $[0,\pi/2]$, $v$ bounds are $[0,9]$.

My work:

$$r_u \times r_v = \langle 4\cos(u), -4\sin(u)\rangle$$
$$\Vert r_u \times r_v\Vert  = 4$$

$$\int_0^9\int_0^{\pi/2}(4\cos(u)+4\sin(u))\,4\,du\,dv= 72?$$

Comment: $r_u\times r_v$ should be a 3 dimensional vector.

Comment: @Kuifje it has a 0k component. Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. I think your error must be in the last line: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E9%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D(4%5Ccos(u)%2B4%5Csin(u))%5C,4%5C,du%5C,dv gives 288.

Answer (score 1):

First of all u need to tell us what u are integrating.
Here i am assuming that u want to calculate

$\int\int_S (x + y) dS$

U are correct in that $dS=\| n(u,v) \|$ where n is the normal on surface S

$r_u'(u,v)=(-4\sin{u},4\cos{u},0)$
$r_v'(u,v)=(0,0,1)$

So in that we get 
$$
\|n(u,v)\|=\|r_u'(u,v)\times r_v'(u,v)\|=\|(4\cos{u},4\sin{u},0)\|=\sqrt{16}=4
$$

With that we have

$$
16\int_{0}^{9}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos{u}+\sin{u} \space dudv=16*9*\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos{u}+\sin{u} \space du 
$$

$$
=144(\sin{u}-\cos{u})|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=144(1-0-(0-1))=2*144=288
$$